# Using Rails console to insert an array of data

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, console

If I want to insert a record into my model I usually do something like this within the Rails console:

```
m = ModelName.create(name: 'This is my name')
m.save
```

But if I have an array

```
['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3' ]
```

How can I create a record for each of the items in the array using the Rails console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as below :

```
records_to_create = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3' ].map { |val| {:name => val } }
ModelName.create records_to_create
```

[`#create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) documentation is clear on this :-

> Creates an object (or **multiple objects**) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

Doco has some examples too :-

```
#..
# Create an Array of new objects
User.create([{ :first_name => 'Jamie' }, { :first_name => 'Jeremy' }])
```